# Add an option to Flash contex window using Javascript

Tags: javascript, flash, google-chrome

I am tring to create a Chrome extension that adds a contex menu entry when ever the right
mouse button is clicked.

I also need for the new entry to be displayed when the right click is on a flash object (Such as Youtube clip) I cannot find a way to do it...

Can it be done? What directions should I check?

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot change Chrome's context menu. You could 'hack' Chrome and display a JavaScript/HTML powered context menu, but the current functions will be lost. You might want to submit this as a feature request, though.

Answer (score 0):

Can't do this (not from JavaScript, and *probably* not from Flash, either). The menu that you get when you right-click in a Flash object is generated by your Flash interpreter, not the browser - and IIRC can't be overridden.